# How to maintain CSS styling when convert HTML to PDF using Dompdf in Laravel?

Tags: html, css, laravel

I'm trying to convert a HTML form into PDF but it doesn't seem to match with the HTML design. I'm not using any external CSS file, just pure CSS.

This is the form in HTML which is fine:

[image: HTML format]

This is what it looks like when convert to PDF:

[image: PDF format]

Do I need to use media quary because the size change, or is there another way? This is the code:

Style:

```
<style>
    * {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        
        .invoice_container {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px 10px;
        }

        .invoice_header {
            display: flexbox;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 100%;
            background: #1f1f7a;
        }

        .img_container {
            margin: auto 0;
        }

        .company_address {
            margin-right: 10px;
            text-shadow:
                -1px -1px 0 #000,
                1px -1px 0 #000,
                -1px 1px 0 #000,
                1px 1px 0 #000;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .invoice_header h2 {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .invoice_header p {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .img_container img {
            height: 100px;
        }

        .client_container {
            padding: 10px 10px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .client_container h4{
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .client_container h5{
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .client_container p{
            margin: 0;
        }

        .in_details {
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .item_container {
            padding: 0 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .item_table {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .item_table td, th {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .invoice_footer {
            padding: 0 10px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .invoice_footer h4 {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .note {
            width: 50%;
        }

        .invoice_footer_amount {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .amount_table td, th {
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }

        .in_head {
            margin: 0;
            text-align: right;
            padding: 5px;
        }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="py-12 w-full">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg p-2">
                <div class="flex flex-col">
                    <div class="space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200 w-2/2 mt-10">
                        <div class="invoice_container">
                            <div class="invoice_header">
                                <div class="img_container">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $pic ?>" alt="logo">
                                </div>
                                <div class="company_address">
                                    <!-- <h2><b>Secure Insight Sdn. Bhd.</b></h2>
                                    <p>
                                        2C, BLK 1, Jalan Tinju 13/50,<br>
                                        Worldwide Business Park, Seksyen 13,<br>
                                        40100 Shah Alam, Selangor
                                    </p> -->
                                    <h2><b>Test</b></h2>
                                    <p>
                                    Address<br>
                                    Address 2<br>
                                    Address 3
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client_container">
                                <div>
                                    <h4><b>RECEIVER (BILL TO):</b></h4>
                                    <h5><b>{{ $quote->client_name }}</b></h5>
                                    <h5><a href="#">{{ $quote->client_email }}</a></h5>
                                    <p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{ $quote->client_address }}</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <h4><b>Project Description</b></h4>
                                    <h5><b>{{ $quote->title }}</b></h5>
                                    <p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{ $quote->description }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="in_details">
                                    <h4 class="in_head"><b>INVOICE</b></h4>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Invoice #</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td>XXXXXX</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Date</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><b>{{ $quote->created_at->format('d M Y') }}</b></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_container">
                                <table class="item_table" border="1" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead style="background: #b3b3b3; border: 1px solid black;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Items</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Value</th>
                                            <th>Quantity</th>
                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($quote_items as $items)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $items->title }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $items->description }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $items->value }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $items->quantity }}</td>
                                            <td>RM {{ $items->total }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="4">Total</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>RM {{ $quote->final_total }}</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfooter>
                                    </tfooter>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="invoice_footer">
                                <div class="note">
                                    <h4>Thank You!</h4>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad temporibus praesentium sapiente unde earum dolore voluptatum? Recusandae eaque maxime rem velit maiores necessitatibus ex tenetur fugit omnis? Pariatur, aperiam velit?
                                        Animi non unde nesciunt labore eum voluptate possimus sed. Neque, eveniet at. Adipisci, facere ad ipsum, voluptate quos blanditiis incidunt repellat reiciendis cum numquam aut rerum est doloremque eos maxime?
                                        Perspiciatis enim velit beatae incidunt cumque possimus libero consequatur. Doloremque aspernatur qui quibusdam placeat molestiae omnis saepe mollitia consequatur, corporis nobis voluptatibus, in magnam vero voluptates unde nulla perspiciatis fuga.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="invoice_footer_amount">
                                    <table class="amount_table" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Tax Amount</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><b>XXXXXX</b></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Grand Total</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><b>4334234234</b></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you make your HTML page narrower you'll get the same layout as you have in your PDF. One option would be to make the PDF page wider, another is to define separate CSS rules for the HTML page and the PDF output.

Comment: If you use inline css instead of internal css block that might solve your problem.

Comment: I also notice that some of the CSS are not loaded completely, like my company address which has text-shadow property. In the HTML it shows but not the PDF. Does Dompdf restrict some CSS elements?

Comment: DomPDF has some documentation in a [Wiki](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Requirements). This documentation has a [CSSCompatibility table](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility) which shows you that "text-shadow" is not supported.

Comment: Well now I know why. Justify Content is not supported. Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes, there are always multiple ways of doing things. You need to do a bit of experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Your Invoice exhibits nearly all the classic reasons why HTML and PDF have significant incompatibilities when being converted, one way or the other.

[image]

PDF printer margins are traditionally "Wide" for 2 prime reasons.
1a) Printers needed wider margins called "Gripper margins" to stop rollers smudging the inked bordering body contents on each side.
1b) The printer can optionally also apply a marginal head line and foot line of textual data in the top and bottom spaces between the rollers, such as page numbering etc.

2. Books traditionally have a need to keep body text away from the spine and for aesthetic reasons that meant a fairly balanced gap on each side.

Clearly such niceties dont apply to a PDF but are retained as the intended usage is a Printout.

HTML CSS does not need to consider such tradition and thus a potential simple way to marry the 2 is set CSS Media Print Page Margin 0 when printing, however that then cascades through all other settings and means that page breaks (PDF does not have those) becomes a greater problem.

Basically Invoices should be designed in a Paged editor such as an Office Application where Maths Macros can control data, and Headers Layout Styles etc. can be controlled for printing.

So to get a result like this is a simple single line, since PDF requires the page size be set first. However you need to design your CSS to now handle the margin less body and thus handle headers, footers of tables and ppage breaks, same as in a word processor.

```
<style>
@media print { @page { margin: 0; size: 210mm 297mm ; } body { margin: 0; } }
    * {
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with what you say about the reasons for margins, but saying that invoices should be designed in an Office Application, with Math Macros, is just weird. Does that actually work? Do you have an example for DomPDF? (I assume here that you don't.) I also don't think setting the margin to zero is a good idea, because, as you said, the margin is needed for printing. Invoices are still often printed.

Comment: OK, I agree that Word processors are made to print text on paper, which invoices often are, but HTML is perfectly able to render invoices. The issue here is that HTML was made for browsers, not for printing on paper like PDF. The disconnect is between HTML and PDF, and not between invoices and HTML. I guess it would be possible to work with a word processor and get it to produce HTML that can, somehow, also be converted to PDF, but from the question I gather this has to be done in [PHP](https://php.net). There are easier ways to do this in PHP than using a word processor.